# Start at the beginning of control, not the middle

Tags: ms-access, vba

When a mask is applied to a control like ...

```
Me.item_name.InputMask = ">!CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
```

and user clicks in that control the cursor is where they clicked, not at the beginning.

```
Me.item_name.SelStart = 0
```

fixes that.  I am trying to loop thru all controls with.

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
ctl.SelStart = 0
Next ctl
```

Ya ... not working.

I have also tried ...

```
For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case Ctl.ControlType
      Case acTextBox
          Debug.Print Ctl.Name
          Ctl.SelStart = 0
      Case Else
    'nothing to do
    End Select
Next
```

Get a RunTime error 2185 on the  Ctl.SelStart = 0

Comment: Not all control types have an `InputMask` or `SelStart` property. You need to catch the relevant controls in your `For...Each` loop using `TypeName`.

Comment: Also the `.ControlType` property of the control can be used.

Comment: not setting mask with loop just the SelStart.  I will get more selective with the loop but if there are no errors shouldn't the setting be applied to the txtbox's?

Comment: Another solution is to iterate through all the `.Properties` collection of the control to make sure you're only working with controls that have a SelStart property. I'll add this as an answer, I think it's the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fail for any controls that don't have a `.SelStart` property, such as CommandButtons.

The `.Properties` collection of the control will tell you if it has a `.SelStart` property, i.e.

```
Sub ResetControls(f As Form)

    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In f.Controls

        Dim p As Property
        For Each p In c.Properties

            If p.Name = "SelStart" Then
                c.SelStart = 0
            End If

        Next p

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I am using the open form event, the above does not work.  When/how is your code applied?

Comment: You'd have to call it by passing the form into the procedure, i.e `ResetControls MyForm`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This is going to take a bit to digest.

Comment: ResetControls (frm_qry_master_niin_add) - Object Required Error

Comment: I think you're just passing the form typename - try passing `ResetControls Forms("frm_qry_master_niin_add")`

Comment: That worked to call the procedure but now it does not like c.SelStart.  Error is "You can't reference a property or method for a control unless it has focus.  I got this same error with the approach I was trying.

Comment: had to add c.setfocus just before c.selstart.  Also have some hidden stuff that needs to be addressed but I think this will do it.

Comment: Although it finished without error, still not working.  Will keep digging and report back with fix so that others may possibly benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the text control's `OnGotFocus` event (which occurs when the user clicks or tabs into the control), and set `SelStart` there instead. The drawback is that you need to write the event for each control, so you can't do it in a loop. The advantage is that it's extremely simple to do, and you can add other functionality to the event for a specific control if needed (like updating from the content of another control).

Comment: Thank you.  This was my first approach but thought it was repetitive for 18 controls.  I am trying to push my skill level up by learning the loop.